# iframe doesn't work properly with IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, iframe

My HTML code doesn’t work properly on Chrome and IE11.

I have a master page with a menu and an iframe to display the rest of the pages of my website, I need this to have a fixed menu.

Now in my second page displayed I have this

```
<li><a href="#profil">Profilo</a></li>
<li><a href="#muro">Dati Anagrafici</a></li>
<li><a href="#polizze">Polizze del cliente</a></li>
<li><a href="#polizze_famiglia">Polizze Famiglia</a></li>
<li><a href="#schedacliente">Scheda Cliente 1.0</a></li>
```

and then this

```
<section id="profil"  runat="server" class="well" style="height:430px;"></section>
```

in Firefox if I click on the anchor menu all is correct. in Chrome and IE if I click on anchor, my menu in the master page go hidden in auto. It seems that the page is cutted.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sorry but i don't see anything about urgent or similar

Comment: no one can help me?